# Sorting (Quicksort) ,Partition

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

```
void swap(int *a,int *b)
{
   int temp;

   temp=*a;
   *a=*b;
   *b=temp;
}

void partition(int a[],int size)
{
   int *right,*left,pivot=a[0],temp;

   right=&a[size-1];
   left=&a[0];
   while(1)
   {
      while(*left<=pivot)
      {
         left+=1;
      }

      while(*right>pivot)
      {
         right-=1;
      }

      if(right<left)
      {
         swap(&a[0],right);
         break;
      }

      swap(right,left);
   }
}
```

**Is this code right?The pivot is getting placed in the right position but at hackerrank they said the right portion should be sorted in ascending order and the left portion of the array should be sorted in descending array.**

Comment: _Is this code right?_ -- Try executing it?

Comment: The code does not look complete. You run from the left up to the first element that is on the wrong side, the same from the right, then swap them and then break the loop. so you swap only one pair? what if there are more?
Also there are the recursive calls missing.

Comment: This is the code for partition not quicksort,so I dont think there will be any recursive calls.The code runs correctly in the sense that ,the pivot gets placed at the right position but I was concerned about the order of elements on left and right side of the pivot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not right: it does not do a stable partition of the array.

Imagine your array is

```
100, 33, 333, 22, 222, 11
```

After the stable partitioning around the first element, it should become

```
33, 22, 11, 100, 333, 222
// 33, 22, and 11 in the same order as in the original array
// 333 and 222 in the same order as in the original array
```

But, instead, it becomes

```
22, 11, 33, 100, 222, 333
```

<sub>Note that this partition  implementation is ok for a non-stable quick sort: the pivot element is in the final position, all elements to its left are smaller, and all elements to its right are larger.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) you don't really sort elements in each partition.

After you chose a pivot value and do the partitioning, all the elements to the left of the pivot are less than the pivot but **in any order**; all the elements greater than the pivot are to its right **in any order**; the pivot is in its final place.

So hackerrank is wrong or, more likely, you misinterpreted what they say.

Comment: It looks like they want a *stable* implementation of quick sort. What I get from there is: *"the numbers should remain in the same order"* which is not the same as the numbers should be in order. Note that this requirement is not mandatory for general QuickSort implementations.

Comment: so basically you are trying to tell me that this partition works right if i use quicksort algorithm along with this?

Comment: Basically, I'm saying QuickSort is not a stable algorithm but you can choose to implement it in a stable way.